# Restrict registration by email

Tags: users

I'm looking for a way to restrict registering in a Drupal 7 site to a particular domain. This was handled with Access Control in Drupal 6, but that feature has been removed.

Modules that are currently available (User Restrictions, User Domain Email) are not working.  I've tried setting up the Rules module to manage this but can't get it to work (with and without trying to use in conjunction with Login Toboggan.)

Comment: Original topic poster was asking about 6.22 - this is specific to 7.10. Also the User Restrictions module listed as a solution in the previous topic is non functional.

Comment: There was another response showing how to do it with validation, that should work fine on D7. If you have a specific question about implementing that, you can post it here (with code) and we can help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Great. Did not think the example there would work for 7. Will give it a shot.

Comment: Found a similar working solution here: http://drupal.org/node/1405368